# C++ - Getting and setting member variable within same method?

Tags: c++, virtual, setter, getter

I have a class that derives from a base class that contains its own member variable. In order to keep everything in the classes encapsulated, I'm trying to figure out a clean approach to setting this member variable at the same time retrieving it in the same method. Here is what the method looks like (this is pseudo code and probably won't compile):

```
class Base
{
    virtual void MyVirtualMethod(double &output1, Object &output2)
    {
        // do base class stuff (does not set output1 because it does not need to)...
        output2 = whatever;
    }
}

class Derived
{
public:
    virtual void MyVirtualMethod(double &output1, Object &output2)
    {
        // do derived class stuff...

        m_DerivedMember = whatever;

        // do more stuff...

        output1 = m_DerivedMember;
        output2 = whatever2;
    }

private:
    double m_DerivedMember;
}
```

Calling code #1

```
std::vector<DataPack> dataPack;

for each Base pointer...
{
    double output1(100); // some default value
    Object output2;
    base->MyVirtualMethod(output1, output2);

    dataPack.push_back(DataPack(output1, output2));
}
```

Calling code #2

```
double output1(100); // some default value
Object output2;
base->MyVirtualMethod(output1, output2);

// do more stuff but does not actually use output1, just output2...
```

While this works, it just doesn't seem clean to me. I guess the bigger question I'm asking myself is whether it's a good idea to use the same method as a getter and a setter at the same time? Thanks!

Comment: _"I guess the bigger question I'm asking myself is whether it's a good idea to use the same method as a getter and a setter ..."_ You don't have any getter/setter functions shown in your samples?

Comment: I meant whether it's a good idea to set and get a member variable within the same method. It's not labelled as a Get or Set method but inside the method it's setting and getting that member variable.

Comment: That's something called a _state operation_ (nothing to do with getters/setters). Without allowing such, the whole concept of OOP would be pretty useless.

Comment: In C++ "getters" and "setters" are generally referred to as _mutators_ and _accessors_. I see nothing wrong with returning a value from a mutator.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I figured out a different way to clean this up, but it basically involves moving the setter part somewhere else. It's an extra function call, but not the end of the world since this work is not being done on a critical thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question, separate getters and setters are at the core of encapsulation. While it may save you an extra function call, it's much cleaner and safer to have separate functions for getting and setting. Here's some tweaked code to understand better

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void MyVirtualMethod(double &output1, Object &output2)
    {
        // do derived class stuff...

        m_DerivedMember = whatever;

        // do more stuff...

        output1 = m_DerivedMember;
        output2 = whatever2;
    }


/*
The setter
*/
void setDerivedMember(double m){
    m_DerivedMember = m;
}




/* 
the getter
*/

double getDerivedMember(){

    return m_DerivedMember;
}


private:
    double m_DerivedMember;
}
```

And we could invoke these functions like:

```
Derived d(1.5, string("I'm a string"));
d.setDerivedMember(5.00);
cout <<"Derived Member Value: " d.getDerivedMember()<<endl;
```

It would output:

```
Derived Member Value: 5.00
```

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't recommend this, you can return a reference to your member, which will allow you both get/set operations. This is how `std::vector` works by overloading `operator[]`. Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  int m_;
public:
  Foo(int m): m_(m){}
  int& get_set()
  {
     return m_;
  } 
  const int& get_set() const // for const-access
  {
     return m_;
  }
}; 

int main()
{
  Foo foo(10);
  cout << foo.get_set() << endl;
  foo.get_set() = 20;
  cout << foo.get_set() << endl;

  // that's why we need the `const` overload of `Foo::get_set`
  const Foo cfoo(100); 
  cout << cfoo.get_set() << endl;
}
```